# VIM substitution with multiple patterns

Tags: regex, vim, awk, replace, sed

I need to modify set of strings that looks like this:

```
debug("some random text:  val " + arg1);
```

or

```
debug("some random text:  val " + arg1 + " val2 " + arg2);
```

or

```
debug("some random text:  val " + getValue(1) + " val2" + getValue(2) + ".");
```

or any similar combination thereof.  For example there could be 0 or more 'args' that all need to be replaced

into

```
debug("some random text:  val ", arg1);

debug("some random text:  val {} val2 {}", arg1, arg2);

debug("some random text:  val {} val2 {}.", getValue(1), getValue(2));
```

Basically take every argument that matches  + .* + substitute with {} and put the matched argument at the end of the " quoted string " with a comma and in the the same order.
So the general form of theend result should be like this:

```
("this is a quoted {} string with {} tokens {} in it", arg1, arg2, arg);
```

Comment: Your first example looks wrong; it doesn't contain `{}`.

Comment: Would a solution using `:perldo` be acceptable?

Comment: It would be really awesome if someone find a way to do that in one step :D

Comment: The answer by Ruud works well for my purposes since I am doing this manually and validating the results.  However it would be nice if someone knew of an alternative way, perhaps using sed and/or awk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do it in multiple steps. The number of steps needed in the following approach equals the highest number of parameters in any single debug statement, plus one.

Sample text file:

```
debug("some random text:  val " + arg1);
debug("some random text:  val " + arg1 + " val2 " + arg2);
debug("some random text:  val " + getValue(1) + " val2" + getValue(2) + ".");
```

We start by appending an empty string literal where necessary.

```
:g/^\s*debug("/s/[^"[:blank:]]\s*\zs\ze);/ + ""/
```

Notice how line 1 and 2 are affected, but line 3 is not. That is intentional; line 3 already ends with a string literal.

```
debug("some random text:  val " + arg1 + "");
debug("some random text:  val " + arg1 + " val2 " + arg2 + "");
debug("some random text:  val " + getValue(1) + " val2" + getValue(2) + ".");
```

Next, we move every first parameter in position.

```
:g/^\s*debug("/s/"\s*+\([^+]\{-}\)\s*\(+\s*"\(.*\)\)\?\ze);/{}\3,\1/
```

Notice how the second (and following) parameters are unaffected.

```
debug("some random text:  val {}", arg1);
debug("some random text:  val {} val2 " + arg2 + "", arg1);
debug("some random text:  val {} val2" + getValue(2) + ".", getValue(1));
```

Repeat the same command. The easiest way to do this is by pressing `@:`

```
debug("some random text:  val {}", arg1);
debug("some random text:  val {} val2 {}", arg1, arg2);
debug("some random text:  val {} val2{}.", getValue(1), getValue(2));
```

Keep repeating for lines with more than two parameters. Once the command no longer affects any lines, you are done.

Notes:

- I made this under the assumption that each debug statement (including all parameters) occupies a single line.
- The regex used may need some tweaking for more complicated parameter expressions (e.g. expressions which themselves contain `+` operators).
- You are advised to use a diff tool afterwards to manually verify the result.

Comment: Cool, I never knew about `@:`, thanks!  And of course after the first time it gets even easier since you can use `@@`.

Comment: Works like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

For a relatively "closed" solution (you will still need to execute the command multiple times for multiple arguments), repeat this command until there are no more changes:

(e.g. for a single line):

```
:s/\([^"]*"[^"]*\)"\s*+\s*\([^ ,]\+\)\(\s*+\s*"\)\=\(\([^"]*\)"\)\=\(.*\)\([^"]*\));/\1{}\5"\6, \2\7);/
```

Explanation:
The expression breaks the code down into the following nine elements, including seven parenthesized elements (`\1`, ..., `\7`, identified by the order of the opening parentheses) and two non-parenthesized ones (listed as `--` below):

```
/\([^"]*"[^"]*\)"\s*+\s*\([^ ,]\+\)\(\s*+\s*"\)\=\(\([^"]*\)"\)\=\(.*\)\([^"]*\));/
   ----\1-----            --\2---    ---\3---        -\5--         \6    -\7--                                                          
                                                   ----\4----

\1: [^"]*"[^"]\*    " Up to second quote (i.e. up to first closing quote)
--: "\s*+\s*        " The first closing quote and '+' operator
\2: [^ ,]\+         " The first concatenated arg (to be converted into an argument list element)
\3: \s*+\s*"        " The following '+' operator and opening quote of the second string (if present) - discard
\4: \([^"]*\)"      " The second string (if present), so we can close the quotes on our (newly combined?) first string
\5:                 " (Embedded in \4 above) - the second string minus the closing quote (the part we want)
\6: .*              " Everything up to the final quote (if there are any more); no more quotes after this
\7: [^"]*           " Everything else (up to closing paren)
--: );              " The end
```

And elements or sub-elements listed as "if present" etc. are qualified with a `\=`. We build the result we want with `\1`, `\2` (in its new location), `\5`, `\6`, and `\7`.

Add a range or qualifying pattern at the beginning as in @Ruud's answer to do more than one line at once (I tend to just use the range `%`, as in `:%s///` for the whole file, but that could match some unintended lines too).

All the same caveats that @Ruud mentioned apply here too - assumes each statement on one line, may not account for more complicated expressions in the arguments, etc.

An expression like this is an awful lot of work to come up with and debug compared to say a multi-step or scripted approach, but it does make for a fun exercise =).